# Why is this panel like this and what should I do to fix this problem

Tags: lighting, repair

I'm trying to rewire my house and I found this in the attic. What tips could everybody help me with so I can replace this or I can make it better toward the wires or not I'll run in here like this.

[image]

Also I bought a sub panel that's 125 A. Am I able to use that amount of amps on the panel or is it better to get 100 amp breaker panel?

Comment: I sure hope that's an old abandoned panel they left in the attic and just forgot to throw in the trash....

Comment: No Its not an abandoned panel it has live wires and some are really old and other wires are fairly good

Comment: Before you would undertake to make major changes to your wiring yourself you would need to get sufficient knowledge and experience. The changes you are referencing would require a permit and I would expect the permitting authority would require a licensed electrician to do the work.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot that needs to be corrected but it looks to me like it could be salvageable.

I'll focus on the box, there are probably some other issues with supporting the cables and protecting them from physical damage.  Some of the old cloth covered wire may be deteriorated to the point it must be replaced.

I think someone repurposed an old panel as a junction box using terminal blocks to splice wires within the box.  There is no cover, and there are a bunch of other issues (cables coming in over the edges rather than through clamps, improper terminations on terminals, etc.)    Most of these issues can be corrected pretty easily, but I can't see if there's anything worse going on in there - there very well may be.

You could replace this with a large junction box / wireway and new terminal blocks, or simply make wire nut splices instead of using terminal blocks.  You could also break this up into several smaller junction boxes and use wire nuts.

I'd say this is probably one to call in reinforcements.  An electrician will be able to evaluate whether there are serious issues or it's just a matter of cleaning up and replacing a hack junction box.

Comment: I agree there is a lot of problems but, with the cables properly routed through the case with clamps cleaned out and covered it is still legal today. With older homes it is extremely expensive to replace the wiring in the walls. what was done was to create a junction box and run romex to the panel in most cases replacing the old fuses. Then later as remodels or funds are available to update the rooms. Code allows even old K&T to be left in the walls by today's code. The one advantage to remodeling if not opening the walls new wires can be fished down the walls to the outles no staples required

Comment: +1 to "find a pro electrician you can trust" to sort this mess out. Where there's smoke (ie, a terrible mess of diy f***ery), there might be fire. And, sadly, the fire might be literal, rather than figurative. And yes, it's possible that this could cost you a fortune.